# UINavigationController no animations anymore

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, animation, uinavigationcontroller

I have a very weird problem with the UINavigationController on iOS 8, maybe someone encountered this already and can shed some light. I have 2 views: let's say view A and view B
I am using it like this:

```
view A [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];

push to a new view B [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];

push to a new view B [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];

push to a new view B [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];

push to a new view B [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];

push to a new view B [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];

return to view A [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

The problem is that if I play with this for 2 min and go through this like push-push-push-push-pop and again... at some time it stops animating, for either push and pop.
I checked the 1) view controllers they get deallocated on the pop to root, 2) I don't receive any memory warnings, 3) the navigation controller is the rootviewcontroller of the window so why this problem?

I can't find any explanation maybe someone has encountered this already. Also I am mentioning I am not using custom animations, just the plain native push and pop of a normal UIViewController, not even subclassing that so everything is plain native.

Comment: Do you get any warnings in the log? If yes, post them, they could be of help. Thanks.

Comment: Were you testing on a device or simulator?

Comment: absolutely no warning I have my breakpoint on All Exceptions as well... something is disabling my animations but nothing is outputted there

Comment: I am facing the same problem. Any luck?

Comment: It's about the custom animations that you use, check if you are using normal push from the system or in case you have overwritten the animations then check some memory leakage there or the actual code to push and the transitions

Comment: Could you solve that ? Any successes ?

Comment: @kokos8998 try using UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning

Answer (score 0):

@kokos8998 try using

```
@interface AnimatorPushGalleryToGallery : NSObject <UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>
```

and then in view A just add this and will control everything from view B either A->B or B->A (or in case you need something more custom add the same delegate in B as well)

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    self.navigationController.delegate = self;
}

- (nullable id <UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController
                                            animationControllerForOperation:(UINavigationControllerOperation)operation
                                                         fromViewController:(UIViewController *)fromVC
                                                           toViewController:(UIViewController *)toVC
{
    if(operation == UINavigationControllerOperationPush)
        return [AnimatorPushGalleryToGallery new];
    else if(operation == UINavigationControllerOperationPop)
        return [AnimatorPopGalleryToGallery new];

    return nil;
}
```